# Do I have to install a new phpmyadmin to each of my Document Root?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've read that the official documentation says that phpMyAdmin should be installed in the web server's document root.

I want to ask if I have to put one phpMyAdmin for each DocumentRoot I have, or is there a nice workaround to this, like using just one folder of phpMyAdmin?

It seems like a dumb question, but I haven't found any explicit reading about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install just one folder and configure each vhost with an alias to point to this folder. However it depends on whether the users of each vhost need access to the same set of MySQL servers defined in this unique folder installation of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but what do you mean by same set of MySQL servers? I'm totally new to these things and the only idea I currently have is that there should only be one MySQL server running.

Comment: One instance of phpMyAdmin can be used to access more than one MySQL server. In your case, since you have only one MySQL server, it's one more reason to have only one phpMyAdmin folder (plus it's easier to upgrade this way). I assume you are using vhosts?

Comment: Yes, I am using vhosts.