# How do I create aliases that point my document roots (production and vhosts) to the same phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been looking around the web for solutions on how to configure my document roots to point to one phpMyAdmin folder so that I don't have to install phpMyAdmin for every single (v)host I would have in the future.

The one who answered my question ([Do I have to install a new phpMyAdmin to each of my Document root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467600/do-i-have-to-install-a-new-phpmyadmin-to-each-of-my-document-root)) told me about making an alias that points to my phpMyAdmin folder. I'm sorry to be clueless on this, but how do I put up these aliases? I may have overlooked at the answer somewhere already, but please do help me.

Some information:

- Mac OS X bundled Apache
- Homebrew PHP
- Homebrew MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/apache-aliasing-and-redirection/. Maybe the Redirect directive would be the best for your situation. In the configuration for each vhost, add something like

Redirect permanent /phpmyadmin http://example.com/phpmyadmin

Where example.com/phpmyadmin is the place where you have installed phpMyAdmin.